# Page is not working in cpanel using Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created the Laravel Project in a local machine and I created the database also. In the local machine, a project is working without any issues but I uploaded my project file into the shard server Cpanel inside the public_html folder and I access the URL it's saying **This page isn’t working**, **HTTP ERROR 500**.

Cpanel PHP version is 7.0
Laravel version is 5.6

But I moved the content file inside the public folder to root folder (public_html) and I changed the path in index.php file

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
```

And server.php file also I change the path Like this.

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public_html'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public_html/index.php';
```

And My htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “alt-php70” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-alt-php70 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Please help to fix this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all the **public folder** files inside **public_html** folder and the rest of your project files inside another folder which you can name it laravel. Then you shoud change your **index.php** file like this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../laravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Thank you so much and fixed this issue the Cpanel I used alt-php 7.0 and I changed to 7.1 it's working